# Codeigniter Inputting session data from model for a simple authentication system

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, session

Trying to put together a simple login authentication.  Been at this for quite sometime, and I can't find where I'm going wrong. Pretty new to Codeigniter and OOP PHP.  I know there are authentication libraries out there, but I'm not interested in using those.

Model:

```
 function login($username, $password){

    if ($this->db->table_exists($username)){
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get($username); 

        if($query->num_rows >= 1)
        {
        return true;
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'login' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        } 
    }  
    }
```

Controller

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->logincheck();
}
public function logincheck(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('login')){
        redirect('/members');
        }
    }
```

If I just echo from the controller: $this->session->all_userdata(); I get an empty array.  So the problem seems to be that the $data array in the model isn't being stored in the session.

Comment: where are you calling login function ?????????

Comment: I call the login function in the controller's index function.  I didn't want to dilute my question with unnecessary code, but I call the login function with: $this->load->model('main_model');  $this->main_model->login($username, $password);

Comment: Your `return true` stops the script. Therefor it doesn't set any userdata. Set the `return true` after `set_userdata()`.

Comment: Thanks, Robin. That fixed the problem.  I knew it was something stupid and basic like that.

Answer (score 0):

This code is part of your problem. You're asking the database driver if a table with the same name as the username exists, and also trying to get the username and password from the same table.

```
if ($this->db->table_exists($username)){
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get($username);
```

Change the `$username` in `$this->db->table_exists($username);` and `$this->db->get($username);` to whatever table your users are in.

Comment: I check if the table exists because I created a new table for each user.  In my controller, the model's login function returns true, it's just that the $data array is not being put in the session data.

Comment: I... see. Is there a reason you don't just have a table with all your users in it? Surely that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your login function is the issue:

```
if ($this->db->table_exists($username)){
```

This just doesn't look right...  If your user name was admin, there there would need to be an admin table, etc...  I am posting a quick example I recently wrote that seems to get the job done:

```
public function doLogin(){
    $this->db->select('user_pass,user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_name' => $this->input->post('login')));
    if($query->num_rows<1 || $query->row('user_pass')!=md5($this->input->post('password')))
        return false;
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('loggedin'=>true,'user_id'=>$query->row('user_id')));
    return true;
}
```